# Checkout page signs out the user

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

The only way I check if user if logged in to my web app is using the following on the frontend

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

However, I have a cloud-function that I use in order to process a payment, it looks like the following

```
app.post("/payment", function (req, res) {
  const orderId = new Date().getTime();
  mollieClient.payments
    .create({
      amount: {
        value: req.body.amount.amount,
        currency: req.body.amount.currency,
      },
      description: req.body.description,
      //redirectUrl: `http://localhost:5500/project/order.html?id=${orderId}`,
      redirectUrl: `https://......web.app/order.html?id=${orderId}`, 
      webhookUrl: .....
    })
    .then((payment) => {
      res.send({
        redirectUrl: payment.getCheckoutUrl(),
      });
      return payment.getCheckoutUrl();
    })
```

My problem is regarding the redirect URL, the redirect to order page is supposed to display information about that order, but it does not display anything because I set that only logged in users can see it. My question is why does it log out the user. I tried both to redirect to 'localhost' and 'URL-of-deployed-firebase-app' and in both cases it logs out the user. I thought by intuition that Firebase stores auth information to local storage because I can enter to any page I want without have to login. But I think this is not the case here. I am not using any `let token = result.credential.accessToken` tokens to keep track of auth status. What is the problem here and how should I proceed?

Here is Order page

```
function getOrderDetails() {
  const url = new URL(window.location.href);
  let orderId = url.searchParams.get("id");
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
      console.log("User logged in " + user);
      firebase
      .firestore()
      .doc(`orders/${orderId}`)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        let orderSelected = {
          category: doc.data().category,
          delivery: doc.data().delivery,
          description: doc.data().description,
          price: doc.data().price,
          title: doc.data().title,
          quantity: doc.data().quantity,
        };
     // set textContent of divs
     } else {
       console.log("User not logged in " + user);
     }
  });
}

getOrderDetails();
```

Comment: Firebase Authentication by default will persist the user's authentication credentials to local storage, and restore those on the new page. Can you show the code for your new page, and how it uses the the current user?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my redirect code is big but it all starts with call to ```firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()```, ```if (user)``` then retrieve data from Firestore and display the information, but there the ```else``` is executed and nothing is displayed.

Comment: If only the `console.log("User not logged in " + user);` prints and the other log never gets printed, then Firebase is unable to restore the user authentication state. How are you signing the user in, and on what platform are you running this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a new page it takes time to restore the user credentials, as it may require a call to the server. So it is normal that your `onAuthStateChanged()` listener first is called with `null` and only after that with the actual user. So you will have to handle the flow in a way that deals with the initial `null`, for example by waiting a few seconds before assuming that the user session isn't restored.

Alternatively, you can store a marker value in local storage yourself to indicate the was signed in recently, and then on the next page use that to assume the restore will succeed.

Comment: I did not quite understand the alternative solution to this, what do you mean by ```marker value``` and ```restore``` it on the next page?

Comment: Regarding the first suggestion, I used ```setTimeout()``` for waiting few seconds so that user is restored correctly, but without any success. Could you please elaborate the answer, please?

Comment: Let's focus on the first solution rather than the alternative. Can you show your `onAuthStateChanged` listener that for example logs the state it gets, and the `setTimeout` you do?

Comment: I have update the question, I just tried to call  ```getOrderDetails()``` twice and an interval of few seconds between but both time it displays ```null``` for user.

Comment: You should not call `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {` multiple times. Calling it once is enough to attach a listener, that will then be called back into whenever the auth state changes.  If you call it only once, you should get two log outputs. The first time it should be your `console.log("User not logged in " + user);`, the second time it should be your `console.log("User logged in " + user);`. If that is not happening, update your question to include the output you **do** get.

Comment: I updated the question. I just get ```User not logged in null``` , it does not do anything inside ```if (user) {}```. I thought the problem could be that I wrapped ```onAuthStateChanged()``` inside a function and it could not be triggered automatically when auth state changes and I wrapped all my function inside the ```onAuthStateChanged()``` but I still get the same. ```User not logged in null```.

Comment: Can you please provide some details about the alternative solution?

Comment: The best explanation comes from this I/O talk (direct link to the relevant section): https://youtu.be/NwY6jkohseg?t=1309

Comment: yes, the alternative solution solved my problem, thank you very much !